# My app-armeabi-v7a-release is crashing when I'm installing it but app-arm64-v8a-release working fine

Tags: react-native

When I am releasing my react native app, app-armeabi-v7a-release is not opening but for the same release app-arm64-v8a-release this is working fine, but not supporting on all devices.

I'm using 0.70.1 version of react-native